# Getting input and showing the result using customized dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a online table reservation app for android. I need to check the availability of a table once a user selects a particular table. For that I am going to use "Dialogs" in android.

I found that dialogs can be customized. See this [tutorial.](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/01/creating-customized-dialogs-in-android.html)

So I can add a datepicker and get the time from the user from the customized dialog when he selects a particular table. But can I show the result (eg: availability) using the same dialog.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can your dialog in  with more than data and  views , you can make flag  that's represent the state of the code , if

```
if(flag =="table"){
// change layout and data
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datatable);
}
else if (flag =="userform"){
// change the layout to userform
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.userform);
}
```